# text flickers on changing opacity on hover

Tags: css, html, text, opacity, paragraph

I am trying to do something very simple, a para has opacity set to 0, when hovered on parent div the para's opacity changes to 1, there is a change of text happening after the opacity changes, it's not exactly flickering, the text kinda self adjusts itself which is a bit odd.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/7t6GM/

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="para">
    <p> SOME SAMPLE TEXT </p>
 </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
    .para{
         width: 1000px;
         border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .para p{
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 80px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .para:hover p{
        opacity: 1;

        transition:         all 400ms ease;
        -moz-transition:    all 400ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -o-transition:      all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     all 400ms ease;
    }
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Is seems to  work fine for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to change the [`backface-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) property value to `hidden`.

The default value is `visible`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q6q6K/)

```
.para p {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: when I remove `backface-visibility: hidden;` it works too.
why we must use both lines 1 and 2?

Comment: @Alaeddine The `-webkit` vendor prefixed version is still needed for support in Chrome/Safari - see relevant support [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility#Browser_compatibility). The un-prefixed version is for forwards compatibility.